# Looping through multiple columns and rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

In Python, (pandas) I'd like to know how to:

1. Loop through multiple columns and rows so as to...
2. Compare them with some value to...
3. Return the column head after having made a comparison

Say that I have the following dataframe:

```
   month_1  month_2  month_3  value  threshold_reached
0     1000     2000     3000   2500  month_3
1      300      500      700    400  month_2
2        0       10       50     15  month_3
```

Per row, I want to compare the columns `month_1`, `month_2` and `month_3` with the value column and return the column header of the month where the number in the value column is lower than that month, but higher than the previous month (hope this makes sense).

For example, in the first row, the value is 2500, which lies between month 2 and month 3, so month 3 should be returned in the `threshold_reached` column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you have your procedure, so grab a text editor or an IDE and you're good to go ! Good luck !

Comment: How is your data stored? What have you tried so far? What modules are you working with?

Answer (score 0):

```
print df

   month_1  month_2  month_3  value
0     1000     2000     3000   2500
1      300      500      700    400
2        0       10       50     15


df = df.assign(threshold_reached=df.apply( lambda row: row[row.gt(row['value'])].index[0] ,axis=1))


   month_1  month_2  month_3  value threshold_reached
0     1000     2000     3000   2500           month_3
1      300      500      700    400           month_2
2        0       10       50     15           month_3
```

1. create function to find the first number greater than value
2. apply function to each row

the code only works if there is at least one number greater than "value". it will fail if there is no number greater than "value"